# open and read file without locking it in vbs (not .NET)

Tags: vba, vbscript

I try to read a (log) file in vbs with this kind of code (VB.net is not wanted, so staying in VB6 for other consideration is mandatory)

```
' FileName containt the full file path and name (assume it exist and available)
' cstForReading is set before and OK

Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile( FileName, cstForReading)

while NOT ( objInput.AtEndOfStream)
   strNextLine = objInput.ReadLine
   ' some code like
   wscript.stdout.Write strNextLine
 wend
```

but during the code execution, the file is locked and cannot be deleted by other application (but modification is possible). This is especialy true for huge file (could reach several Gb) so no copy are possible (context doesn not allow this) nor load in memory at once.

Is there a another way to open the text file as read only without locking the file (and my code have to deal with missing file during execution) ?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is loaded into memory, then can it be deleted by another program? Although it is read only, it is effectively in use? perhaps this pseudo code may help

vbs file (above) checks for the log file.

```
Create a copy of the log file
load the copy into memory
read the copy log file
```

Other program that may delete log file

```
if applicable delete the original copy file
```

vbs file

```
after reading file close the copy log
delete the copy log file
```

I think this way may give you what you require where you can read from the log and delete the file if it is required.

Comment: i did not mention in post (forget so corrected now) but file could be huge, sone not a solution to copy the file or load it in memory (a readAll was not used for this reason)

Comment: i don't think multiple programs will be able to access a file without one of them locking it. What if after the first script is completed it automatically calls the other program to start?

Comment: this is for a log analyzer so there is often modification of the file read at same time by my script. New info is assumed as lost/inexistant until next read. Problem occurs on file that are recreated by their generator.